# How to handle error when object has no attribute

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. This is my first ever code in Python! Code that works:

```
test = {"name": "John Lennon"};
print (test.get("name", 0).split(" ")[1]);
```

What happens here is that it prints out `Lennon`, which is expected.

If the code is:

```
test = {"age": "John Lennon"};
print (test.get("name", 0).split(" ")[1]);
```

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'` will get printed. I understand that this is because the `0` value can't be split.

Is there a way to elegantly/gracefully handle if the value returned is `0` without using `if else` clause?

Comment: In the `get` method put whatever you want to print when the value doesn't found instead of 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to elegantly/gracefully handle if the value returned is 0 without using if else clause?

The best way to handle this is to provide a default value that allows `split()`. So this means you can use an empty string instead:

```
print (test.get("name", "").split(" ")[1]);
```

However, now you get an error with the indexing. You can solve this error by breaking up the long line of code into smaller pieces and assigning intermediate values to variables:

```
names = test.get("name", "").split(" ")
```

Then use an `if` statement to check if there is a last name:

```
if len(names) >= 2:
```

Comment: You missed the OP's real question

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Avoiding errors is the cleanest way to handle them.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you shouldn't use `get`. Check if the dictionary contains the key you want to access

```
test = {"age": "John Lennon"}
if "name" in test:
    print(test["name"].split(" ")[1])
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: What if the `name` isn’t a 2 or more word string?

Comment: @NChauhan then you should probably turn your dictionary into `{"first_name": "John", "last_name": None}`

Answer (score 1):

The method I would use is a `try-except`

```
try:
    test.get('name', 0).split(' ')[1]
except AttributeError:
    # do something to handle error
```

Obviously in this case, don’t use a 0 as the default value. Use a valid string that won’t cause an error.

```
test.get('name', ' ').split(' ')[1]
```

The more likely error is an `IndexError` which will occur when the name given is only 1 word.

You can stack these `except` clauses like `elif`s:

```
try:
    test.get('name', 0).split(' ')[1]
except AttributeError:
    # do something to handle error
except IndexError as e:
    # you can use ‘as e’ to use the exception
    # e.g print(e)
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    # you can catch multiple exceptions in one clause
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not "name" key in your  {"age": "John Lennon"} dict. When you want to read the "name" member (which does not exist in dict) then "get" method gives 0 as default value. And the type of your default value (0) is integer which does not have split method.
You should define the default value as string. Like this:

```
print(test.get("name", " ").split(" ")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use try/except

```
test = {"age": "John Lennon"}
try:
   print (test.get("name", 0).split(" ")[1])
except:
   print('failed to get name')
```

OR you could change the default return of .get()

```
test = {"age": "John Lennon"}
print (test.get("name", " ").split(" ")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

- Since the value corresponding to *name* is a string, so should be the *get*'s default value. In this case it should be the empty string
- If you want the last name (which will be last element in the list), use ***-1*** index (as it would work even when *split* will not be able to split the string - and therefore will return a list containing the string)

> ```py
> >>> test0 = {"name": "John Lennon"}
> >>> test1 = {"age": "John Lennon"}
> >>>
> >>> print(test0.get("name", "").split(" ")[-1])
> Lennon
> >>> print(test1.get("name", "").split(" ")[-1])
>
> >>>
> ```

Comment: You missed OP's real question

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Avoiding the error in the first place is the best solution.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: I really don't think so. I suggested a better solution than the one (which I assume it's because lack of *Python* experience) that got *OP* into this situation. Returning 0 as a default value to something that is usually a string, doesn't make very much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "elegantly handle".  If you put a space in the default arg for get, you don't get an error:

```
>>> test = {"age": "John Lennon"};
>>> print (test.get("name", " ").split(" ")[1]);

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `try/except`:

```
try:
    test = {"age": "John Lennon"}
    print (test.get("name", 0).split(" ")[1])
except AttributeError:
    # doSomething
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `test.get` will give you the corresponding value to your key. If it cannot find it, it will give you the default value, that you provided as second argument. That is an integer `0` and therefore has no `split`, which is why you get this error. Just use:

```py
test = {"age": "John Lennon"}
print (test.get("name", " ").split(" ")[1])
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm), the `dictionary.get()` method has a keyword argument `default`, which can be set to None like so:

```
test.get(name, default=None)
```

This will return `None` if the key `name` does not exist in the dictionary.  Separating your code into two lines would handle this gracefully:

```
test = {"name": "John Lennon"};
data = test.get(name, default=None)

if data == None:
    print( data.split(" ")[1] )
else:
    print( "Key {0} not found in 'data.'".format(name) )
```

Comment: The second positional argument is the same as the `default` keyword argument. You should give one or the other, but not both.

Comment: You can just as easily do `if data == 0` using the OP's original default value.